# Confusion with Linux Logrotate

Tags: linux, mongodb, cron, logrotate

There is a linux mongo instance wherein the mongo logrotation has been set:

> **/etc/logrotate.d/mongodb**

```
/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log {
   rotate 7
   daily
   size 500M
   copytruncate
   missingok
   create 0600 mongodb mongodb
   dateext
   delaycompress
   compress
}
```

But the **/etc/logrotate.conf** file has the following configuration:

```
weekly

su root syslog

rotate 4

create

include /etc/logrotate.d

/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0660 root utmp
    rotate 1
}
```

The question here is, will the mongo logrotation happen daily as specified in **/etc/logrotate.d/mongodb** or will it happen weekly as it has been specified in **/etc/logrotate.conf** ?

Also how do I know/ensure if the logrotation is actually happening, through cron ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logrotate` must be run by `cron`. On Ubuntu 18.04 `cron` runs `logrotate` daily, see `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.daily`. You can also run it manually.

Global `weekly` is the default, `/etc/logrotate.d/mongodb` overrides it with `daily`.

Answer (score 0):

logrotate.conf is the default configuration file, where the setup is applied to the logs which are not additionally configured in `/etc/logrotate.d/` folder.

The best option is to set `/etc/crond.hourly` to execute the logrotate on every hour. The logs will be rotated only if they are configured hourly or they matching size criteria otherwise the rotation will be skipped.

You can verify the logrotation process in `/var/log/cron` log file.
Also you have an option check `/var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status` file and you can find the rotation history.